# Magento modify the final output in all pages

Tags: php, magento

i need to parse the final output contents (html) of all the pages of this CMS, (using PHP and my own class)

something like:

```
<?php

    echo get_magento_output();
```

to:

```
<?php

    echo parse_content(get_magento_output());
```

Can i create an extension that do this? if not, what files i must modify to modify the output in all pages?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, you can do it here:

```
magento/app/design/frontend/enterprise/themename/template/page/1column.phtml
```

subbing in 1column for whatever the name is for you.  However, I would beg you not to do this.  If you want to modify things on all pages, change the theme or template.  Theres tons of documentation out there on Magento Themes, and there are plenty of places you can alter phtml files to change your output to be correct the first time around.

as example, we have the default header:

```
/app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

If you want to change css classes, of header for example, change:

```
<div class="header">
```

to

```
<div class="my-new-header">
```

the phtml functionality is strong, and you can accomplish a lot in these files.